# Is the relation $P(X \mid Y) \leq P(X \mid Y, Z) $ correct?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are three (discrete) random variables that have the same probability distribution; these variables are not independent of each other.

Without any additional assumption or information, can we claim that 
$$ P(X \mid Y) \leq P(X \mid Y, Z) $$

Comment: No; I'm not sure why you would expect this either, since for instance both sides are probability distributions so they should still sum to $1$ when summed over all values of $x$ for fixed $y$ and $z$.

Comment: A similar property holds for conditional entropy; but for conditional probability this seems unreasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be defined like so: roll a dice and let $X$ be the event "The number is even," $Y$ be "The number is less than or equal to 3," and $Z$ be "The number is odd." You can verify that the probability distributions of the random variables that generated $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all equal.

Now, $ P(X \mid Y) = \frac{1}{3}$, and $ P(X \mid Y, Z) = 0 $